# Visual studios pyglet syntax error

Tags: python, visual-studio, pyglet

I've recently added `pyglet` to my computer but for some reason, although I have correctly installed and configured it, when I go to my visual studios to compile code with it it comes up with a syntax error.

The problem is in the `__init__` file.

If anyone knows how to change the code so it will compile correctly in visual studios I would be very appreciative. Or better yet, how to make it compile without changing the source because I'm sure there are more line that have this issue. 
(I'm running python 3.4.4 if that's relative.

[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFxaP.png)
[The line causing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2PXD.png)

[image]

Comment: Use `print()` the function and not `print` the keyword, thats python 2 only. Also for future reference, please don't post code as images. You should just post it as text, thats less work surely?

Comment: The code you've copy/pasted/used is Python2 specific. The `%` operator was depreciated and you should use `'Called from {}'.format(name)` instead for instance. `print` as also changed to `print()`. The rest looks good.